# Read/store and display mobile data signal on Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an app check the signal of the current device and display it in a textview in dBm. Looked up and read several other questions before posting and most seem to he deprecated/not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [CellSignalStrenght](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrength.html)